# How to get footer at the bottom of the page depending on the content?

Tags: html, asp.net, css

depending on the content in my page how can I get the footer at the bottom ?

In gridview if i select page size above 20 the footer is overlapping on the gridview box.

I tried the CSS property - `position:absolute,bottom:0`; as well as  overflow:auto...

It dint help the footer is remaining in the same place behind the gridview.can someone pls help me 
Thanks.

Comment: Include all the relevant code, and/or a link to your test-site.

Comment: Maybe [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Check this  [fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/cvTUE/)

Format your page layout as in the fiddle. set the `min-height`of your container div to

`total height - (height of header + height of footer)`

(in the fiddle header and footer occupy 15% and 10% height respectively. so the content is given

`min-height:75%; // 100%- (15%+10%)`

so that it'll always occupy that much space even if your actual content is less.

If your content is more the container div will automatically expand and pull down your footer.

if you apply `position:absolute` your element will be taken out of the normal flow, then the footer won't be pulled down by the content if it expands.